# Visual Studio 2010 - Organising Web Application Layout on a Component Level

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, rest

I was wondering how to go about organising components on a c# web application in Visual Studio.

The form contains a series of text-fields each having it's own label. As the labels all differ in length, it causes some alignment issues:

[image]

What are the best practises for organising web components (e.g. 1, 2, 3 columned structures) within a web application project? When developing a Windows Form project the toolbox shows a **containers** section from which you can pick things like TableLayout etc but when within a web application the toolbox doesn't offer this option....

Answer (score 1):

i use an unordered list for my form fields, and so would look something like

```
<fieldset>    
<ul>
    <li><label for="<%= txtField1.ClientID %>">Field name</label><asp:TextBox id="txtField1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

where i would float the label element left, and set a specific width on it, then float the input elements left, and again specify a specific width for the float and the element boxes.

```
ul li{list-style-type:none;width:400px}
ul li label{float:left;width:150px;}
ul li input, ul li select, ul li textarea{float:left;width:224px;margin-left:6px}
ul li input[type=checkbox], ul li input[type=radio]{width:auto}
```

and some other formatting bits specific to my css/template

Answer (score 1):

You'll either want to use a table or a CSS-based solution (like kolin mentions).

Some research has shown that putting the label ABOVE the control actually is "faster to process" from a user's perspective. So you may want to design your forms around that paradigm.

Comment: See this article for more background and advantages/disadvantages for different layouts: http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/web_forms.html